# Geometric phase acquired by a photon on the Poincare sphere

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, berry-pancharatnam-phase

I know that when a photon (spin 1) is parallely transported in the Poincare sphere in a closed loop, the geometric phase which it acquires is 'half' the solid angle subtended by the closed loop at the origin although photon is a spin 1 particle. Is this true for an electron also (spin 1/2) on the Poincare sphere? Is it even valid to talk of an electron associated with the Poincare sphere because Poincare sphere represents the polarization state of an EM field.

This question originated in my mind because when we subject an electron or any particle of spin '$s$' kept at the origin to a magnetic field constant in magnitude but varying direction, the associated geometric phase is '$s\Omega$', where '$\Omega$' is the solid angle subtended by the varying Magnetic field (a parameter of adiabatically varying Hamiltonian) at the origin in the real space.

Comment: Careful - the factor of two comes from the topology of the state space. In the case of the Poincaré sphere, the fiber bundle is the Hopf fibration, and you get the factor of 2. In the case of a wrapped optical fiber (as in Akira Tomita and Raymond Y. Chiao. "Observation of berry's topological phase by
use of an optical fiber", Phys. Rev. Lett., **57**:937--940, Aug 1986) the state space is the tangent bundle of the 2-sphere, which has a different topology from the Hopf and there is no factor of 2 present. I'm not an electron guy, so you need to look into the magnetic field experiment more ...

Comment: ... deeply - I suspect the particle's spin is only a factor to the extent that it bears on the state space topology (actually, this is the only way it can be a factor)

Comment: By state space topology you mean the topology of the parameter space? That is same for both an electron and photon in case when we subject them to magnetic field. Then why do we have different factors for both? Will the same happen for Poincare sphere as well?

Comment: I mean the full quantum state space - in the case of light polarizations represented by the $2\times1$ Jones vector for the Poincaré sphere - before we quotient away phases common to the two elements through the Hopf map to get the Stokes parameters. In the case of the wrapped optical fiber, the state space is the Poynting vector (moving on the sphere surface) together with the polarization plane angle.

Comment: Really appreciate your insight into this question. I am just a beginner in this field and not much aware of the concept of topology and bundles. I am currently reading Topology by Nakahara. Can you suggest if it's a good starting point?

Comment: It's subtle but fun stuff. Have a look at the early chapters of Schutz, "Geometrical Methods for Mathematical Physics". I haven't read Nakahara. For the Poincaré sphere, a practical and thorough discussion can be found in [David W. Lyons. "An elementary introduction to the Hopf Fibration", Mathematics Magazine, **76** (2):87 -- 98, 2003](https://nilesjohnson.net/hopf-articles/Lyons_Elem-intro-Hopf-fibration.pdf). It gives you a good concrete discussion to launch off into the more abstract discussion of fiber bundles. Niles Johnson also has some beautiful stuff on his web page on this subject.

Comment: David has given you the general answer for the Berry connexion arising from a quantum Hamiltonian, which I guess you're most interested in. I would draw your attention to the fact that often anholonomies not arising thus are also called "Berry Phases" and the state spaces have different topologies, as in my wrapped fiber example. For more on the Hopf fibration (which is probably a lower priority for you now), see [my document here and its references](http://www.light-stithy.com/documents/HopfFibration.pdf). If it's too big (30MB with hires figs), let me know and I'll make a smaller copy.

Comment: Section 3.5 of the document "The Curious Factor of 2" is most relevant to you. However, I discuss this as a property of the Fubini-Study metric appropriate to the higher dimensional sphere rather than the general discussion for Hamiltonians in David's answer, which is probably more useful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Poincaré sphere as a parameter space is not exclusive to neither photons nor electrons. It can appear in the evolution of various physical systems; for example the dynamics among two hyperfine atomic states driven by a laser beam. Please see the following work by [Viennot](http://perso.utinam.cnrs.fr/~viennot/publi/JMathPhys_48_052102.pdf)  for a general characterization of generic parametrization spaces.

One important property of the parameter spaces is that they are Kählerian, i.e., symplectic with a compatible complex structure. The computation of the symplectic form is very easily performed as a byproduct of the Berry phase computation as follows:

Suppose we have a family of Hamiltonians $H(R)$ parametrized by a parameter space $\mathcal{M} \ni R$. Suppose that $\psi(R)$ is a normalized eignevector corresponding to the eigenvalue $E(R)$ of $H(R)$:
$$H(R) \psi(R) = E(R) \psi(R)$$
Suppose that the parameters $R$ are varied such that the level $E(R)$ does not cross any other level; then the Berry connection:
$$A = \psi(R)^{\dagger} d \psi(R)$$
Let $P(R)$ be the projector on the state $\psi(R)$:
$$ P(R) = \psi(R) \psi(R) ^{\dagger}$$
Then the symplectic structure of the parameter space $\mathcal{M}$ is given by:
$$\omega = \mathrm{tr} \left(P(R) dP(R) \wedge dP(R)\right)$$

(It is not hard to check that $\omega$ is closed). When the parameter space is the Poincaré sphere, $\mathcal{M} = S^2$, the symplectic structure is always an integer multiple of the Poincaré sphere area element, irrespective of the Hamiltonian that we started from.
$$\omega = n \omega_{S^2}$$
(with $\omega_{S^2} = \sin \theta d\theta d\phi$ in spherical coordinates).

Thus only the parameter $n$ determines the how many multiples of the solid angle are equal to the Berry phase.

The symplectic form of any parameter space computed as above is integral, i.e., its flux through any two dimensional cycle divided by $4\pi$ is an integer). The reason for that is only then, the Berry connection will be a connection on a line bundle. This happens when the Dirac's quantization condition ($n\in \mathbb{Z}$ is satisfied).

The requirement of the Berry phase to be a bundle holonomy is very important; for example it is the deep reason behind the classification of topological insulators.

Now, in order to know what is the integer $n$ corresponding to a physical situation, one only needs to compute the eigenvector:

For example, for a spin $s$ electron in a magnetic field, the Hamiltonian is
$ H = \mathbf{\sigma} \cdot  \mathbf{B }$
Here $\mathbf{\sigma}$ are $2s+1 \times 2s+1$ matrices. If we take the eignevector corresponding to the state $(m_s, s)$, we get:
$n = 2 m_s$
Thus for the case of the electron $m_s = \pm \frac{1}{2}$, we get $n= \pm 1$.

I the case of the photon, the polarization dynamics takes place in the plane perpendicular to the direction of motion. The Hamiltonian is two dimensional. The explicit form of the Hamiltonian is given for example in: the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.2136)  by Bliokh, Niv, Kleiner and Hasman:
$$H = S_z  \mathbf{A(p)}\cdot  \dot{\mathbf{p}}$$
($S_z$ is the third component of the Stokes vector, $\mathbf{A(p)}$ is the spin orbit interaction)

Thus in this case also, we have $m_s = \pm \frac{1}{2}$, we get $n= \pm 1$, even though the eigenvalues of $S_z$ (the helicities) are equal to $\pm 1$.